# Somar todos os valores que estão no banco de dados e mostrar na tela

Tags: php, mysql

Poderiam me dar uma ajuda, tenho uma tabela onde preciso mostrar o total de valores, no caso somar todos os valores que esta no banco de dados e mostrar na tabela. Minha tabela chama anúncios e a coluna de valor chama (valor).

```
<tr>
    <th style="text-align:center;">Valor Total:<?php
    $sql = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM anuncios WHERE valor = :valor");
    ?></th>
</tr>
```

Comment: qual o banco de dados? existe um método "sum" para fazer somas no banco

Comment: Você pode usar `SUM`. `SELECT SUM(valor) FROM anuncios WHERE valor = :valor`

Comment: Isso está retornando algo ? Falta muita coisa ! Se tiver, é simples: `SELECT SUM(valor) FROM anuncios`

Comment: Não, ainda não esta retornando, não sei como prosseguir, sou novo na área de PHP.

Comment: Já mostramos como conseguir

Comment: @MarcosA.Massini você ja testou no seu banco as querys que o Rafael ou o Raoni passou ? pq era pra elas terem funcionado

Comment: @ViniciusShiguemori sim, se eu dar um `print_r($in);` ele pega normalmente, agora se eu dar um `echo $In->valor;` ele da erro.

Comment: Só que ai ele fica **Valor Total:stdClass Object ( [SUM(valor)] => 12121 )**

Answer (score 1):

Não sei se você sabe como retornar os valores, mas baseado no meu comentario a cima, segue o codigo base.

```
$sql = $pdo->prepare("SELECT SUM(valor) FROM anuncios");
$sql->execute();

$ln = $sql->fetchObject();

echo $ln->valor;
```

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: valor in C:\xampp\htdocs\controle.php on line 70
stdClass Object ( [SUM('valor')] => )

Comment: Como você manda o parametro para ser usado no `WHERE`? é POST mesmo? pois coloquei POST ali de exemplo, você tem que colocar conforme é sua necessidade

Comment: Vou te mostrar como ta meu código inteiro.

Comment: @MarcosA.Massini Isso, melhor, pois ai consigo resolver.

Comment: Eu não entende pra que você usa o `WHERE` ali editei minha resposta, testa dessa maneira e me fala o que deu

Comment: Deu certo, não tem uma maneira de fazer ele mostrar apenas o valor, ao invés de : Valor Total:stdClass Object ( [SUM(valor)] => 12121 )

Comment: @MarcosA.Massini Editei meu codigo, só tirar o print e colocar o echo como fiz a cima

Answer (score 0):

O select é esse:

```
SELECT SUM(valor) FROM anuncios
```

Como irá tratar e exibir, aí não tem como saber com esse pedaço do código.
Se quiser, poste inteiro.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php require 'pages/header.php'; ?>
<?php
    if(empty($_SESSION['cLogin'])) {
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">window.location.href="login.php";</script>   
        <?php
        exit;
    }
?>
<div class="container"> 
    <h1 align="center">CONTROLES</h1>

    <a style="margin-left: 510px;" href="add-anuncio.php" class="btn btn-success">Adicionar Dados</a><br/><br/>

    <table class="table table-striper">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Foto</th>
                <th>Cliente</th>
                <th>Categoria</tb>
                <th>Valor</th>
                <th>Vencimento</tb>
                <th>Descrição</th>
                <th>Estado</th>
                <th>Ações</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <?php
            require 'classes/anuncios.class.php';
            $a = new Anuncios();
            $anuncios = $a->getMeusAnuncios();

            foreach($anuncios as $anuncio):
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <?php if(!empty($anuncio['url'])): ?>
                <img src="assets/images/anuncios/<?php echo $anuncio['url']; ?>" width="100" height="40" border="0"/>
                <?php else: ?>
                <img src="assets/images/logo.png" width="100" height="40" border="0"/>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </td>
            <td><?php echo $anuncio['titulo']; ?>
            </td>
            <td>
                Cebola
            </td>
            <td>R$ <?php echo number_format($anuncio['valor'], 2); ?></td>
            <td>
                <?php echo $anuncio['data']; ?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?php echo $anuncio['descricao']; ?>
            </td>
            <td><?php if($anuncio['estado']==1) {?><strong>PAGOU</strong><?php }else {?><strong>NÃO PAGOU</strong><?php };?></td>
            <td>
                <a href="editar-anuncio.php?id=<?php echo $anuncio['id']; ?>" class="btn btn-warning">Editar</a>
                <a href="excluir-anuncio.php?id=<?php echo $anuncio['id']; ?>" class="btn btn-danger">Excluir</a>
            </td>

        </tr>
        <?php endforeach;
        ?>
        <tr>
        </tr>
            <thead align="center">
                <tr>
                    <th style="text-align:center;">Valor Total:<?php 
                    $sql = $pdo->prepare("SELECT SUM(valor) FROM anuncios WHERE valor = ?");
                    $sql->execute(array($_POST['valor']));

                    $ln = $sql->fetchObject();

                    print_r($ln);

                    ?></th>

                </tr>
        </thead>
</table>
```

Comment: `$sql = $pdo->prepare("SELECT SUM(valor) FROM anuncios");`   Como respondi acima

Comment: Consegui com esse código.

Comment: `<?php 
      
     $sql = $pdo->prepare("SELECT SUM(valor) FROM anuncios");
$sql->execute();

$ln = $sql->fetchObject();

print_r($ln);
     
?>`

Comment: Não tem como fazer ele mostrar apenas o valor ao invés disso ?. Valor Total:stdClass Object ( [SUM(valor)] => 12121 )

Comment: Teria outras formas de fazer sem ser pelo prepare também.

Comment: use "echo $ln" ao invés de print_r, ou se tiver em array, "echo $ln[0]" ou "echo $ln[valor]"

Comment: no caso seria `echo $ln->valor` pois é um objeto, editei meu codigo a cima

Comment: Valor Total:
Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$valor in C:\xampp\htdocs\controle.php on line 75         Ele ainda esta retornando esse erro, apliquei seu código acima rafael.

Answer (score 0):

Use o [**`AS`**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/problems-with-alias.html) do mysql para criar um "apelido" que seja acessível no `fetchObject`/`fetchAssoc`:

```
<tr>
    <th style="text-align:center;">Valor Total:<?php

    $sql = $pdo->prepare("SELECT SUM(valor) AS total FROM anuncios");
    $sql->execute();

    $ln = $sql->fetchObject();

    echo $ln->total;

    ?></th>
</tr>
```

Use o `WHERE` se deseja filtrar de um usuário logado na sessão, assim:

```
<th style="text-align:center;">Valor Total:<?php

$sql = $pdo->prepare("SELECT SUM(valor) AS total FROM anuncios WHERE id_usuario=?");

//Passa o ID do usuário para a query
$sql->bindValue(1, $_SESSION['id_do_usuario'], PDO::PARAM_INT);

$sql->execute();

$ln = $sql->fetchObject();

echo $ln->total;

?></th>
```

Comment: Ae muito obrigado, e Guilherme um exemplo, se eu quiser somar apenas oque consta o usuário que esta logado, e não tudo que esta no banco de dados eu faço oque?

Comment: @MarcosA.Massini não tenho como saber amigo, isso não consta na pergunta, até aonde vejo só tem a tabela de anuncios, mas no geral seria via `WHERE`, por exemplo `SELECT SUM(valor) AS total FROM anuncios WHERE usuarioid=[aqui vai o id do usuario logado]`, esse id passado deve estar em uma sessão.

Comment: Assim entendi, só que ai complica demais, por que os usuários esta salvando tudo junto no banco.

Comment: Qual a estrutura da tabela anuncios? @MarcosA.Massini

Comment: id : como INT chave primária e auto increment             id_usuario: INT        id_categoria: INT       titulo: VARCHAR 100     descricao: TEXT       valor: FLOAT           estado: INT                    data: DATE

Comment: @MarcosA.Massini então cada anuncio é um "usuário" também?

Comment: Guilherme eu tenho um sistema de "estado" que no banco de dados é 0 e 1, e coloquei pra quando mostrar 0 esta PAGO, e quando estiver 1 printar NÃO PAGO, eu tentei fazer uma verificação para mostrar o valor total apenas dos que estão escrito NÃO PAGO, que no caso é o valor 1,

Comment: @MarcosA.Massini então tente assim `$pdo->prepare("SELECT SUM(valor) AS total FROM anuncios WHERE id_usuario=" . $idDoUsuarioQueQuerFiltrar);`

Comment: Então, no caso cada um tem seu id, porque são contas cadastradas, eu coloco oque?, desculpa o incomodo, é que estou aprendendo agora rsrs.

Comment: Os usuários ficam em tabelas diferentes, no caso ficam na tabela usuarios.

Comment: @MarcosA.Massini ajudar eu quero, mas esta dificil entender, você quer cruzar dados, tipo `JOIN`?

Comment: Não olha tipo vou lhe explicar direito. Eu quero que o valor total mostrado seja apenas daquele usuário que esta logado, e não dos outros, no caso cada usuário tem seu id. Ai eu quero que ele só consiga o valor total dos anúncios dele. Quando o usuário adiciona anúncios tem um formulário que de seleção que se ele selecionar PAGO vai com id 1, e se ele selecionar NÃO PAGO vai com id 0, ai eu queria que os valores mostrados fossem apenas do usuário e no caso mostrar apenas os que estão como NÃO PAGO. Entende?

Comment: Fazendo assim todos que forem editados como PAGO, irem dando "Baixa", no caso tirando o valor total e sobrando apenas os que estão como NÃO PAGO.

Comment: @MarcosA.Massini Mas é exatamente isto que o código que postei no comentário anterior faz ... Marcos `$_SESSION['cLogin']` é o ID ou o login? Qual a variavel de sessão contém o ID do usuário? Veja a edição que fiz na minha resposta com um exemplo de passagem de sessão.